# How to consume WCF service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

i am new to C# development, as a first task i got assigned with WCF service, and tried some samples in code project.
Now i am working with complex types, but unable to get the response.
from the wsdl file and xsd using svcutil.exe wsdlname xsd and got two files based on those files created one service in local and trying to consume in the below way.

Below is Interface

I am able to run this service able to see the service url and able to refer in my client.

Below is i am trying to call the service from client to this stub, but not able to get the idea ,how to call

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.ServiceModel;

    namespace ConsoleApplication3
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                 ServiceReference1.sendMessageResponse1 s = new
ServiceReference1.sendMessageResponse1();
                 ServiceReference1.sendMessageResponse1 s1 = new ServiceReference1.sendMessageResponse1();
                 //s1.messageid = 1;
                 //s1.recipient = "Chiranjeevi";
                 //s1.status = "Sent";
                 //ServiceReference1.sendMessageResponse ss= (ServiceReference1.sendMessageResponse) s1;
                 Console.Read();            
             }
        }
    }
```

But while trying to call the service i am not getting any out put for default constructor also. tried with console.writeline();

I am trying to call the
sendMessageResponse1 sendMessage(sendMessageRequest request); from service.

getting the below error, while trying to call the above method.
Error   1   Cannot convert type 'ConsoleApplication3.ServiceReference1.sendMessageResponse1' to 'ConsoleApplication3.ServiceReference1.sendMessageResponse'

Comment: We really didn't need to see all that code. You could have narrowed down the problem quite a bit. See [How to Consume a Web Service](https://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/).

Comment: Could you pare down the code in your question to the relevant parts? You should be able to at least narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: @MattD: at the time of consuming i am not getting response, highlighted in bold part, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're trying to convert an instance of one class to an instance of another.

```
ServiceReference1.sendMessageResponse1 s = 
    new ServiceReference1.sendMessageResponse1();
ServiceReference1.sendMessageResponse1 s1 = 
    new ServiceReference1.sendMessageResponse1();

//s1.messageid = 1;
//s1.recipient = "Chiranjeevi";
//s1.status = "Sent";
//ServiceReference1.sendMessageResponse ss=
//    (ServiceReference1.sendMessageResponse) s1;
```

The following line of code will break, because there is not a conversion between class `sendMessageRequest` and `sendMessageRequest1`.

```
ServiceReference1.sendMessageResponse ss=
    (ServiceReference1.sendMessageResponse) s1;
```

Here is the deal:

- `s1` is of type `sendMessageResponse1`.
- Your trying to cast it into a type of `sendMessageResponse`.
- That isn't going to work, because the former isn't derived from the latter.

That's exactly what the error is telling you:

> Error 1 Cannot convert type 'ConsoleApplication3.ServiceReference1.sendMessageResponse1' to 'ConsoleApplication3.ServiceReference1.sendMessageResponse'

Comment: @Luttin: trying with lots of options by mistake lastly i placed that code.                 actually need to call this method:   confusing what are the parameter need to pass and about return type of this method, could you help me out                          sendMessageResponse1 sendMessage(sendMessageRequest request);

Comment: @Chiranjeevi I'm afraid I just ran out of time to provide further assistance. I have a new task at work.

Comment: @Luttin:no probs, i am also trying from my end, if got succeeded will post here.thanks for concern

Answer (score 0):

After lots of googling got the below url, which is the best kind of beginner who stuck directly into the project without knowledge in WCF.
Best starting point article.

https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/implementing-wcf-service-real-world